# Cocos2d performance issue on simple code

Tags: iphone, performance, graphics, cocos2d-iphone, frame-rate

I am writing a tile base game and my frame rate dropped from 60 to 30 after I loaded the tile textures and building textures onto the screen.  After days of googling and trying different solutions, I am still not able to figure out the cause.

To isolate and understand the issue.  I had created a simple project which it displays 100 sprites at random position when program is load, and do absolutely nothing afterwards, in the HellowWorld layer :

```
// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
if( (self=[super init])) {

    CCTexture2D *vlo_Texture = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-72.png"]];

    CCSprite *vlo_Temp[100];
    NSInteger vli_X, vli_Y;
    for (NSInteger vli_Counter=0; vli_Counter<100; vli_Counter++)
    {
        vli_X = arc4random()%480;
        vli_Y = arc4random()%320;
        vlo_Temp[vli_Counter] = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:vlo_Texture]; //[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon-72.png"];
        vlo_Temp[vli_Counter].position = ccp(vli_X, vli_Y);
        [self addChild:vlo_Temp[vli_Counter]];
    }

}
return self;
}
```

The fact that the code above runs only 30fps shocks me.  I do not have a timer to refresh these sprites.  I believe the system should just draw all the sprites and do nothing (I assume ?)

I had tried to apply :

```
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444];
```

and

```
if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
    [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeMainLoop];
```

however they do not improve the performance at all.  Is there anything else I can do?

Thanks in advance.

Alex

Comment: It might help people to help you if you say what OS version and what device you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> After days of googling and trying different solutions...

but [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

---

Try putting all of your sprites that are using the same texture into a `CCSpriteBatchNode`. This allows these sprites to be rendered with just one `glBindTexture` call, a call which is quite slow.

```
CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Icon-72.png"];
for (NSInteger vli_Counter=0; vli_Counter<100; vli_Counter++)
    {
        vli_X = arc4random()%480;
        vli_Y = arc4random()%320;
        vlo_Temp[vli_Counter] = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:vlo_Texture]; //[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon-72.png"];
        vlo_Temp[vli_Counter].position = ccp(vli_X, vli_Y);
        [batchNode addChild:vlo_Temp[vli_Counter]];
    }

[self addChild batchNode];
```

Comment: Thanks James, in my program I had sprites in individual files, in the last few days I changed that to a sprite sheet, and I tried settings like [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444];
and
if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
    [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeMainLoop];

Comment: Add all your sprites to that spritesheet and use the spritesheet texture as a parameter for the batchnode.

Comment: Thanks, I will give batch node a go now :)

Comment: I just used Zwoptex to create a spritesheet for this and used the following code :

            [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Untitled_default.plist"];
        CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Untitled_default.png"];
        CCSprite *sprite1 = nil;
        for (NSInteger vli_Counter=0; vli_Counter<100; vli_Counter++)
        {
            sprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Icon-72.png"];

Comment: vli_X = arc4random()%480;
            vli_Y = arc4random()%320;
            sprite1.position = ccp(vli_X, vli_Y);
            [batchNode addChild:sprite1]; 
        }
        
        [self addChild:batchNode];

however the speed is still 30fps, any other tips?  Thanks

Comment: Does the spritesheet contain the sprite "Icon-72.png"?

Comment: Yes it does, I've just tested it on iPhone 4 and it runs 60fps, i guess it's just my mac book's not fast enough :p

Comment: 30fps was in my simulator, thanks James for pointing me to the CCSpriteBatchNote, i am reading this article and it seems very interesting : http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/09/cocos2d-spritebatch-performance-test/#more-3365

Comment: The simulator uses a software renderer whereas the devices use hardware acceleration making rendering much faster anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to performance ... have you tried running on a device ? the simulator falls very short of actual 'iSomething' performance, especially when dealing with HD pics and numerous sprites.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the time it takes to run two different blocks of code, I recommend using [BNRTimeBlock](https://gist.github.com/2006587), as described on [this Big Nerd Racn Weblog post](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=316).